# how to create mysql database backup file in windows

Tags: mysql

I wrote the following code in cmd but it showing an error

```
>  cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
>     mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] [database name] > C:\[filename].sql
```

error

> A required privilege is not held by client

Comment: I think there's a required privilege that is not held by client

Comment: Can you write a file to C:\[filename].sql when you save from Notepad (for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use this:

`mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql` **to export**

`mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql` to **import**

Comment: Now error is Access is denied

Comment: @rehan use cmd.exe with Administrator Privilege

Comment: thanks a lot it worked

Comment: @rehan can u arrow-up my answer or approve it ? for SO Community